# Is Nandez (Wood Harris) a Blade Runner in Blade Runner 2049?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049, blade-runner

What do we know about [Nandez](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Nandez?so=search) from Blade Runner 2049? He's with K in the police coroner's office scene. Clearly LAPD, but is he a Blade Runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [script](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/blade_runner%20(2049).pdf) describes him as a cop, not a blade runner.

> A pug COP, NANDEZ, enjoys the show. A bigot with a mouth certain
> whatever comes out of it is funny. Recognizable as human as all humans
> stuck on Earth seem to be.